# How to disable the Solr Admin web UI in 7.X

Tags: solr, solrj

How to disable my `solr` admin web UI in 7.x
or is there any way to make it secure with username/password

Let me know if any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The Solr Admin interface is just a set of static HTML pages - it would not do anything useful to disable the web ui.

The interface uses a large set of API endpoints under Solr, and you'll have to lock down those endpoints as you see fit.

You can do this by using a `security.json` file as shown in [Authentication and Authorization Plugins](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_6/authentication-and-authorization-plugins.html). The whole list of endpoints you can allow or disallow is also available under [Permission attributes](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_6/rule-based-authorization-plugin.html#permission-attributes) for the rule based authorization plugin.

In general, the best advice is to firewall off Solr by itself and only allow trusted clients to talk to it - i.e. not expose it directly to your users in any way, and only let a trusted middleware application talk to it. That way you won't end up misconfiguring Solr itself, and only exposes the features that you actively use.